# Is there a name for this exercise/movement?

Tags: exercise, movements

When I stand with my feet flat and together, then lift myself onto my toes repeatedly. It's a pretty good calf workout, and I do about three reps of 100. Is there a name for this exercise/movement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are [Calf Raises](http://www.wikihow.com/Do-Calf-Raises). Calf raises are used to strengthen the lower legs. Calf raises may sometimes help with shin splints depending on the location of the pain.

Toe raises are the opposite lift and should be done in conjunction to avoid muscle imbalances. Stand flat footed and lift your toes towards your shin bone.

Comment: Straight forward, quick answers. These sites are awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Care to elaborate on what the use of the exercise is? Not that its required, but it just hurts my eyes to see 4 word answers ;-)

Comment: I knew this in a different form as the "donkey press" - see http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Gastrocnemius/WTDonkeyCalfRaise.html

Comment: @ivo I figured since I normally write a rambling book, this might be a nicee departure from the norm. :)